# A couple of basic questions about prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

1. Does there exist a general algebraic formula for evaluating the $k^{th}$ consecutive prime number (in terms of $k$) when the set of prime numbers is arranged in an ascending order?
2. Does there exist a general algebraic formula (in terms of $n$) for evaluating the largest prime number $p$ less than or equal to any given natural number, $n$?

Comment: No, prime numbers are complicated.

Comment: Could you be somewhat more specific what you mean by "general formula"? Note there are various methods to determine prime numbers, but no general algebraic formula exists which does what you're asking about. For more info, please check Wikipedia's [Formula for primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes).

Comment: Thank you for that Wikipedia link. Wilson's theorem is definitely useful and illuminating.